# Whenever the id is different create a new complete loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a query that has several lines with the same id. Here is an example of what it returns:

| Id | valor em divida | Descrição |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 552 | 50.00 | Fraldas |
| 552 | 35.00 | Creme |
| 545 | 23.00 | Caneta |
| 545 | 15.00 | Caderno |

Now I'm looping in js to return the data like this:

```js
var data = [
   {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
];

$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function(){
var linha = ``;
  
  linha += `<div>
              Assunto: Aviso de pagamento
              
              <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover">
              
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Nº Recibo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Data de Vencimento</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>                              
               <tbody>`;               
               Object.keys(data).forEach(i=>{ 
               
               Id = data[i].Id;
               valor = data[i].valor;
               Descricao = data[i].Descricao;
       linha += `<tr>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${Id}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${valor}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${Descricao}</td>
                 </tr>`;
               })
    linha += ` </tbody>
             </table>
             
             De V. Exas.
             Atenciosamente 
           </div>`;
          $('#minhaDiv3').show();
          $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);     
});
```

```css
$(function() {
  $(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $(el).show();
    $("section > div").not(el).hide();
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(".btn-hide").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $(el).hide();
  });
});

function mostra(div){    
  $(".esconder > div").hide();
$('.' + div).show();    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" href="s3" data-element="#minhaDiv3">Teste</button>

<section id="s3">
   <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv3">
      <div class="row pagmfalta">

      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

But I intended that whenever the Id was different, it would separate in this way:

```
Assunto: Aviso de pagamento
Nº Recibo   Data de Vencimento  Valor
552 50.00   Fraldas
552 35.00   Creme
De V. Exas. Atenciosamente

Assunto: Aviso de pagamento
Nº Recibo   Data de Vencimento  Valor
545 23.00   Caneta
545 15.00   Caderno
De V. Exas. Atenciosamente
```

If you notice the code above it returns all the information even though the Id is different at once.

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not change the code such that it matches your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group first and then `forEach` the result like:

```js
var data = [{
    Id: "552",
    valor: "50.00",
    Descricao: "Fraldas",
  },
  {
    Id: "552",
    valor: "35.00",
    Descricao: "Creme",
  },
  {
    Id: "545",
    valor: "23.00",
    Descricao: "Caneta",
  },
  {
    Id: "545",
    valor: "15.00",
    Descricao: "Caderno",
  },
];
var results = data.reduce(function(results, org) {
  (results[org.Id] = results[org.Id] || []).push(org);
  return results;
}, {});
$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {
  var linha = ``;
  Object.keys(results).forEach(i => {
    linha += `<div>
              Assunto: Aviso de pagamento
              
              <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" border="1">
              
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Nº Recibo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Data de Vencimento</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>                              
               <tbody>`;
    Object.keys(results[i]).forEach(b => {

      Id = results[i][b].Id;
      valor = results[i][b].valor;
      Descricao = results[i][b].Descricao;
      linha += `<tr>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${Id}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${valor}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${Descricao}</td>
                 </tr>`;
    })
    linha += ` </tbody>
             </table>
             
             De V. Exas.
             Atenciosamente 
           </div>`;
  });
  $('#minhaDiv3').show();
  $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" href="s3" data-element="#minhaDiv3">Teste</button>

<section id="s3">
  <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv3">
    <div class="row pagmfalta">

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is what I intend. I just have a question when applying it to my code.. So I have like this `$.getJSON('valreceber.php', function (data) {`, now how do I get the Id value here in this part of the code `(results[org.Id] = results[org.Id] || []).push(org);`, always returns undefined

Comment: Same code, put my code between `{}` of `getJSON`

Comment: I don't understand, I'm putting it like this: `$.getJSON('valreceber.php', function (data) { var results = data.reduce(function(results, org) { (results[org.Id] = results[org.Id] || []).push(org) return results;; }, {}); });`, but it returns like this: `{undefined: Array(18)}`. As it returns undefined at the beginning, it does not separate by ids as in the answer you posted here. can help

Comment: The problem is that here `results[org.Id]` returns undefined

Comment: can you `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: @Anónimo you can `console.log(results)` into my snippet, if the data is same work perfectly.

Comment: It returns the array, look at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ySX4.png). This is what console.log(results) returns;

Comment: @Anónimo As i said just see the final result [img](https://ibb.co/NLWWnSZ)

Comment: Yes I realized that. The problem is that I can't get the value that comes from the Id in this part of the code `results[org.ID]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250013/discussion-between-anonimo-and-simone-rossaini).

Comment: May I ask you for help with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74655246/print-multiple-pages-with-footer)